# Solving system of 4 equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following system of four equations with four unknowns: $vt, v\phi, pt, p\phi$.
[image: system of equations]

The author of the paper that I am reading right now presents the following solution to the above equations as:
[image]
In order to show this initially, I used the function `Solve` to get the solution:

```
 Solve[{fa pt^2 - a^2 p\[Phi]^2 == m^2, 
   fa vt pt - a^2 v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == m, 
   fd/2 vt pt - 
     a v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == (s fd)/4 v\[Phi] pt - (s fdd a)/
      4 vt p\[Phi], (s fd)/(2 a) vt pt - s v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == 
    v\[Phi] pt - vt p\[Phi]}, {vt, v\[Phi], pt, p\[Phi]}]
```

But unfortunately, it gives me a very long output that doesn't make sense to me. Will there be any other ways to solve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Given system of equations involves $pt, p\phi, vt, v\phi$  while potential solutions are given in terms of $pt_{\pm}, p\phi_{\pm}, vt_{\pm}, v\phi_{\pm}$.   How are these variables related?

Comment: Notice that they differ from sign in some of the terms.

Comment: Perhaps it is assumed that both $pt_{+}$ as well as $pt_{-}$ are different solutions. It hasn't been stated explicitly.  You can find solutions assuming certain variables e.g. `Simplify[With[{fd = 1, fdd = 1, s = 1, a = 1}, Solve[{fa pt^2 - a^2 p\[Phi]^2 == m^2, 
    fa vt pt - a^2 v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == m, fd/2 vt pt - a v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == (s fd)/4 v\[Phi] pt - (s fdd a)/4 vt p\[Phi], (s fd)/(2 a) vt pt - s v\[Phi] p\[Phi] == v\[Phi] pt - vt p\[Phi], m > 0, fa > 1/2}, {vt, v\[Phi], pt, p\[Phi]}, Reals]], m > 0 && fa > 1/2]`

Comment: In the first line you posted, you are writing  p\[Phi]^2, interpreted as (p^phi)^2, however the formula say p^phi^2 = p^(phi^2).
Note that p^phi^2 is always bound to mean p^(phi^2), since (p^phi)^2 = p^(2*phi)!

Comment: No my dear, you can always define variables as "products" of two letters/characters. MMA will recognize that p\[phi]^2 will always be the square of the variable $p\phi$.